# TypeError: ownProps.match is Undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux, mapstatetoprops

Unable to find a solution to the error **TypeError: `ownProps.match` is undefined**.

I am following a tutorial on `react-redux` and firebase to build a to-do app. The below code gives the component where I am redirected to when I click my Task/project on the home dashboard and get the data of that sepcific project in the projectDetails page from the firestore.

The `ownProps` in the `mapStateToProps` function is casuing the error mentioned.

Any help to solve this error or alternative way to implement this code will be appreciated.

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase'
import { compose } from 'redux'

const ProjectDetails = (props) => {
  const { projects } = props;
  if (projects) {
    return (
      <div className="container section project-details">
        <div className="card z-depth-0">
          <div className="card-content">
            <span className="card-title">{projects.title}</span>
            <p>{projects.content}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="card-action grey lighten-4 grey-text">
            <div>Posted by {projects.authorFirstName} {projects.authorLastName}</div>
            <div>2nd September, 2am</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="container center">
        <p>Loading project...</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  // console.log(state);
  const id = ownProps.match.params.id;
  const projects = state.firestore.data.projects;
  const project = projects ? projects[id] : null
  return {
    project: project
  }
}

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  firestoreConnect([{
    collection: 'projects'
  }])
)(ProjectDetails);
```

Facing issue in the above code here:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  // console.log(state);
  const id = ownProps.match.params.id;
  const projects = state.firestore.data.projects;
  const project = projects ? projects[id] : null
  return {
    project: project
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass the router configs to the mapStateToProps, you need to use the `withRouter` wrapper.

Mentioned in the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter).

This should work:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  // console.log(state);
  const id = ownProps.match.params.id;
  const projects = state.firestore.data.projects;
  const project = projects ? projects[id] : null
  return {
    project: project
  }
}

export default compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  firestoreConnect([{
    collection: 'projects'
  }])
)(ProjectDetails);
```